# error con laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel

estoy siguiendo un turial para Laravel 5.3 y estoy en la implementacion de un arrito de compras pero tengo un error en todo el proyecto por haber llamado a una variable en la siguiente archivo:

resourses/layouts/app.blade

donde coloco:

```html
<li>
    Mi carrito
    <span class="circle-shopping-cart">
        {{$shopping_cart->productsSize()}}
    </span>
</li>
```

Tengo creado el model de ShoppingCArt:

```html
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class ShoppingCart extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ["status"];
    
    public function productsSize(){
        return 20;
    }
    
    public static function findOrCreateBySessionID($shopping_cart_id){
        if($shopping_cart_id)
            return ShoppingCart::findBySession($shopping_cart_id);
        else
            
            return ShoppingCart::createWithoutSession();
    }
    
    public static function findBySession($shopping_cart_id){
        return ShoppingCart::find($shopping_cart_id);
    }
    
    public static function createWithoutSession(){
        
        return ShoppingCart::created([
            "status" => "incompleted"
        ]);
    }
}
```

y este es su controlador:

```html
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;

use App\ShoppingCart;

class MainController extends Controller
{
    public function home()
    {
        $shopping_cart = ShoppingCart::findOrCreateBySessionID(null);
        return view('main.home',["shopping_cart" => $shopping_cart]);
    }
}
```

Pero me da un error que me dice que el error esta aqui:

```html
<li>
    Mi carrito
    <span class="circle-shopping-cart">
        {{$shopping_cart->productsSize()}}
    </span>
</li>
```

NO VEO EL ERROR

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: añade por favor el error que te muestra

Comment: ok lo  añadiré ahora mismo

Comment: pegue una buena parte, me indicas si necesitas el resto del mensaje

Comment: en la linea 58 de app.blade tengo:  <li>
    Mi carrito
    <span class="circle-shopping-cart">
        {{$shopping_cart->productsSize()}}
    </span>
</li>

Comment: la verdad me mataste

Comment: muchachos gracias, pude reolver rompiéndome los ojos un rato... fue un error de sintaxis